# How do I access events from an iCalendar feed?

Tags: curl, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to understand iCalendar feeds and have read through the specification ([RFC 5546](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546)) and thought I'd try to simply request events from a public iCalendar feed.

I ran this to attempt to get a list of weather events from Google's public weather calendar:

```
curl -X GET https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/p%23weather%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics
```

and I get this response:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:UTC
END:VCALENDAR
```

but no event data. Have I misunderstood how data is retrieved from an iCalendar web address? How can I access event data from an iCalendar feed like this?

Comment: I think google calendar depends on location. Might be because of this, it is not giving any details

Comment: If that were the case, how would I set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the calendar you've chosen is empty, as importing it back into Google Calendar will verify. Try the same approach with one of the other calendars e.g. days of the year, and you should see events as expected:

```
curl -X GET https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/%23daynum%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics
```

The specification you've linked to is for iTiP, a protocol to support scheduling of events, such as creating or deleting new events. The calendar output you've quoted conforms to the specification since it includes a `PUBLISH` method, which means that the output is simply listing events without requiring any action on behalf of the client. This would suggest that the calendar output is complete i.e. not an incremental update of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as tmw says, that ics feed is empty.

IF you want a feed with events for testing, this is a fun one:
the eccentric holidays (all day events): https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/0bajvp6gevochc6mtodvqcg9o0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

this one has moon phases for sydney 
https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/ht3jlfaac5lfd6263ulfh4tql8%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

If you want one with times, create your own 'extra' google calendar or find a website with classes that has an ics feed.